# Error when altering stored procedures and functions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, ddl, stored-functions

Using SQL Server Management Studio, I'm getting the following error when I try to alter a stored procedure or user-defined function:

> Msg 9455, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AuditDDLChanges, Line 18
>   XML parsing: line 34, character 28, illegal qualified name character

This error happens even when I haven't made a single change to the code. All I do is right-click a stored procedure or UDF in the Object Explorer and choose "Modify" (alternatively "Script Stored Procedure as" > "ALTER To" > "New Query Editor Window").

Without making a single change to the generated script, I'm getting the error above.

Now here's the really spooky part: This does not happen with all my objects, and furthermore, if I execute the code inside the stored procedure by itself, everything works just fine.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that another admin user had created a Database Trigger named "AuditDDLChanges". This trigger would listen for DDL_PROCEDURE_EVENTS, DDL_TABLE_VIEW_EVENTS, DDL_TRIGGER_EVENTS and DDL_FUNCTION_EVENTS and insert a record into a log table for each such event.

For some reason though, the code of this trigger failed to parse some of the XML returned from the EVENTDATA() function.

After disabling the trigger, I no longer get the error above, which is why I'm marking this question as answered.